# Como colocar un salto de línea en document.write() con comillas ` `(backticks)

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando colocar un salto de línea en este código ya sea al final o al inicio pero no he podido.
se como se hace con el formato de comillas dobles pero si me pudieran ayudar con este soy nuevo en esto

```
else if (montoPedro<0.6){
    document.write(`A pedro no le le alcanza para ningún helado`)
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no usar comillas dobles? PD. Ahí estás usando backticks, no comillas simples: `'a pedro no le alcanza'`

Answer (score 3):

Estás escribiendo en el DOM, y el DOM interpreta html no texto plano, por tanto, para lograr el salto de línea usa `<br>`. El problema no son los los `backticks`.

Si quieres lograr un salto de línea con backstick en donde se admita esta sintaxis, simplemente presiona enter. Te adjunto un ejemplo en consola.

```js
document.write(`A pedro no le le <br> alcanza  para ningún helado`)

console.log(`A pedro no le le 
alcanza  para ningún helado`)
```

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó